# How to diff two mails in outlook

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, diff

I know a guy who is always re-sending me (rather long) emails with little changes. (i.e. a changed name or date)

Is there an easy way (preferrably an addin in outlook) to visual diff (visual like kdiff3 or windiff) outlook mails?

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible in Outlook; but you can save the two emails as separate MS Word documents (.docx or .doc) and compare them using MS Word's document comparison feature.

Comment: Good idea. BTW: My current way is to copy the text into Notepad++ and use it's comparison feature.

Comment: Copy emails  to two Word documents and use compare (under the review tab as in Office 365 circa 4/18).  It adds revision tracking twixt the 2 docs.  Super useful.

Answer (score 1):

The tool I often use for this sort of tasks is kdiff3 (especially if you are looking for difference in text). It is an opensource tool and you can simply select all, copy and paste the content of the one email to the left and repeat the process with the other email to the right side of the kdiff3 program window. It's fast and efficient :-)

Comment: Thanks, @gmarcan. While I do like kdiff3 it does compare "only" text and not outlook mails.